# php query ignoring order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to display 10 rows and order them by the highest score first, the code runs with no errors but it's still just displaying them in the order they appear in the database.

```
$questionScore = query('SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY score = :score DESC LIMIT 10',
array('score' => ['score']),
$conn);
```

This is my query statement -

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   $stmt->execute($bindings);

   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

   return $results ? $results : false;
}
```

My function used

Comment: Don't understand why you're doing `ORDER BY score = :score DESC`: Simply doing `ORDER BY score DESC` should work

Comment: Doesn't my function require a binding though as one of its params? Sorry I'm new to this ^^

Edit - 
I understand what you mean now sorry, yeah that works thanks my mistake there.

Comment: Bindings aren't mandatory, and you'd normally only use bindings if you were applying a WHERE clause, or wanted the result binding directly to variables.... it's your function that's making them mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your function that's forcing you to set a binding when it isn't necessary

```
$questionScore = query(
    'SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10',
    array(),
    $conn
);


function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   if (!empty($bindings))
       $stmt->execute($bindings);

   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

   return $results ? $results : false;
}
```

or even reorganise the arguments to your function, so you don't need to pass empty bindings if they're not needed:

```
$questionScore = query(
    'SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10',
    $conn
);


function query($query, $conn, $bindings = array())
{
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   if (!empty($bindings))
       $stmt->execute($bindings);

   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

   return $results ? $results : false;
}
```